# UNNotificationPresentationOptions vs UNMutableNotificationContent.interruptionLevel

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios15

I'm confused why is UNNotificationPresentationOptions is needed
in completion handler when the disturbance level is determined by iOS since 15 based on UNMutableNotificationContent.interruptionLevel?